# stop left bar button from being shifted right when back button has no title in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am removing the title to the back bar button in the navigation bar with:

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)`

This works great, however, I have a problem when I add a left bar button for another action to the navigation bar with:

`self.addLeftBarButtonWithImage(UIImage(named: "menu_lines")!)`

The left bar button shows up shifted right from the back bar button as if the back bar button still has title text. I would like the new left bar button to be right beside the back icon '<', but there is horizontal space in-between that I can't figure out how to remove.

[image]

Comment: Try self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu_lines")!, style: .Plain, target: self, action: nil) without second line

Comment: This isn't what I need because I want to keep the back < caret image and back action and add a second left bar button for another action.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding them with `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = []`
 and add UIBarButton objects to the array! You must set your own actions in this case but it should take care of what you're trying to do